# Android Return from background : how to manage code?

Tags: android, caching, background, android-activity

When I'm back from the background, `onResume()` method is called. Okay. So if I want to do some special code when I'm back I can put it there.

What about if I've many activities ? Do I've to duplicate that code everywhere ? Should I used the Application class and call a method in each `onResume()` methods ?
Plus, I would need to access the UI (changes, dialogs, ...). Maybe the application class isn't that a good idea ... ?

**Concretely**, I want to refresh my cache every XX time and I want to do that check when the application (or activity) is back from the background but I don't know exactly how to do and where to do that.

How do you do that guys ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If it is similar code you could use a static helper functions class and pass `this` to the functions as the context so that you can do Activity specific functions.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Isn't there something easier ? Such as the applicationDelegate in iOS ?

Comment: There are no delegates in java (unfortunately) and I have never programmed in iOS, so I am not aware of what an applicationDelegare is.

Comment: An alternative would be a BaseActivity from which all Activities subclass from.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know when an APP is returning from background state (when you return to home or another app and back to your app again) maybe this can help you.
if you find a case when this do not apply, please let me know.

---

```
public class FatherClass extends Activity {

      private static int activities = 0;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String clase) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      protected void onRestart(){
           super.onRestart();
           if(activities == 0){
                 Log.i("APP","BACK FROM BACKGROUND");
           }
      }

      protected void onStop(){
           super.onStop();
           activities = activities - 1;
      }

      protected void onStart(){
           super.onStart();
           activities = activities + 1;
      }
}
```

---

All of your classes MUST extend from this one, or increment and decrement the value of this class.